# Paths in php not working

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a navigation bar I include in my pages, which worked fine as long as all the php files were in the same dir. Once I moved them into folders the navigation bar would only allow one link to be clicked then once in a lower dir the pathing to files were incorrect.

Dir structure:

php-->

- navpanel.php
- search.php
- user folder

  - checkusername.php
  - etc php files
- database folder

  - createdatabase.php

js-->

- js files

php code im using which is included in the other files.

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
echo $path;
if ($_SESSION['admin'] == 1){
    echo '
        <body>          
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="search.php">Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></span> User</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="user/createuser.php">Create User</a></li>
                        <li><a href="user/edituser.php">Edit User</a></li>
                        <li><a href="user/deleteuser.php">Delete User</a></li>
                        <li><a href="user/usergroup.php">User Groups</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Databases</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="database/createdatabase.php">Create Database</a></li>
                        <li><a href="database/editdatabase">Edit Database</a></li>
                        <li><a href="database/deletedatabase">Delete Database</a></li>
                        <li><a href="database/databasegroup">Database Groups</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="../connect/logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
            </ul>         
        </body>';
}
else {
    echo '
        <body>

            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="search.php">Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="connect/logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
            </ul>

        </body>
    ';
}
```

Comment: What happens when you point to the root? `/user/createuser.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the HTML output. If you want the links to be relative from the root (`http://www.example.com/`), then you should use `/user/createuser.php`, `/user/edituser.php`, etc.

Although unrelated to your links, you are referencing the session variable `$_SESSION['admin']` without calling `session_start();` at the top of your script. Session variables return null if you don't call `session_start();`.

Comment: Hazzah! Will be selecting you in 8 min.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start(); // u forgot to place this
$path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
echo $path;
if ($_SESSION['admin'] == 1){....
```

Comment: Thanks I did miss that as-well.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your links to something like:

```
echo '<li><a href="'.$path.'user/createuser.php">Create User</a></li>';
```